# The cost of passing by shared_ptr

Tags: c++, performance, shared-ptr

I use std::tr1::shared_ptr extensively throughout my application. This includes passing objects in as function arguments. Consider the following:

```
class Dataset {...}

void f( shared_ptr< Dataset const > pds ) {...}
void g( shared_ptr< Dataset const > pds ) {...}
...
```

While passing a dataset object around via shared_ptr guarantees its existence inside f and g, the functions may be called millions of times, which causes a lot of shared_ptr objects being created and destroyed. Here's a snippet of the flat gprof profile from a recent run:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name
  9.74    295.39    35.12 2451177304     0.00     0.00  std::tr1::__shared_count::__shared_count(std::tr1::__shared_count const&)
  8.03    324.34    28.95 2451252116     0.00     0.00  std::tr1::__shared_count::~__shared_count()
```

So, ~17% of the runtime was spent on reference counting with shared_ptr objects. Is this normal?

A large portion of my application is single-threaded and I was thinking about re-writing some of the functions as

```
void f( const Dataset& ds ) {...}
```

and replacing the calls

```
shared_ptr< Dataset > pds( new Dataset(...) );
f( pds );
```

with

```
f( *pds );
```

in places where I know for sure the object will not get destroyed while the flow of the program is inside f(). But before I run off to change a bunch of function signatures / calls, I wanted to know what the typical performance hit of passing by shared_ptr was. Seems like shared_ptr should not be used for functions that get called very often.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

-Artem

**Update:** After changing a handful of functions to accept `const Dataset&`, the new profile looks like this:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name
  0.15    241.62     0.37 24981902     0.00     0.00  std::tr1::__shared_count::~__shared_count()
  0.12    241.91     0.30 28342376     0.00     0.00  std::tr1::__shared_count::__shared_count(std::tr1::__shared_count const&)
```

I'm a little puzzled by the number of destructor calls being smaller than the number of copy constructor calls, but overall I'm very pleased with the decrease in the associated run-time. Thanks to all for their advice.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327573/c-passing-references-to-boostshared-ptr

Comment: Related issue: on some platforms (e.g. older ARM), the reference counting requires locking a mutex. This can make shared pointers unusable (except by reference) in a real-time context.

Comment: How did you get this nice looking benchmark data?

Comment: @Daniel: This is just the [flat profile](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Flat-Profile.html) from `gprof`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Always pass your `shared_ptr` by **const** reference:

```
void f(const shared_ptr<Dataset const>& pds) {...} 
void g(const shared_ptr<Dataset const>& pds) {...}
```

**Edit:** Regarding the safety issues mentioned by others:

- When using `shared_ptr` heavily throughout an application, passing by value will take up a tremendous amount of time (I've seen it go 50+%).
- Use `const T&` instead of `const shared_ptr<T const>&` when the argument shall not be null.
- Using `const shared_ptr<T const>&` is safer than `const T*` when performance is an issue.

Comment: thats what I do - there are safety issues here but they are corner cases. I would rather have a slightly slower correct app than a dead fast app. Was your test app a testbed or the real code ?

Comment: @pm100: Note that I'm passing by *const* reference, not just by reference, which prevents most of the safety issues while offering a significant performance boost. When the alternative is passing the raw pointer contents of the shared_ptr, this method is safer.

Comment: This has been my original design, but the related question linked by Fred made me a little hesitant to stick with it.

Although, the calls to f() and g() are fairly tight and I can guarantee that they will not reset pds (either directly or indirectly). So, I guess the question is which is more efficient

    void f( const shared_ptr<Dataset const>& pds ) {...}

or
    
    void f( const Dataset& pds ) {...}

It seems like the difference is simply where the dereferencing happens: inside or outside f().

Comment: @Artem: If your method requires `pds` to be non-null, definitely prefer `const Dataset&`. You only need to pass a `shared_ptr` if null is a valid value.

Comment: [Herb Sutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Sutter) [recommends](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/C-11-VC-11-and-Beyond) just passing by raw pointer/ref (43min in), unless you want to do something like store it.

Comment: For readers who do not know the safety concerns - if your function deletes data **or** modifies containers in a way that invalidates references **or** calls another function that does the former, it can get very tricky to ensure that your reference will never dangle.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass by copy and then move in the callee?

Answer (score 15):

You need shared_ptr only to pass it to functions/objects which keep it for future use. For example, some class may keep shared_ptr for using in an worker thread. For simple synchronous calls it's quite enough to use plain pointer or reference. shared_ptr should not replace using plain pointers completely.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using [make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html), could you give that a go? By locating the reference count and the object in the same area of memory you *may* see a performance gain associated with cache coherency. Worth a try anyway.

Comment: Memory locality does not reduce the number of function calls but still usually speed things up.

Answer (score 3):

Any object creation and destruction, especially redundant object creation and destruction, should be avoided in performance-critical applications.

Consider what shared_ptr is doing.  Not only is it creating a new object and filling it in, but it's also referencing the shared state to increment reference information, and the object itself presumably lives somewhere else completely which is going to be nightmarish on your cache.

Presumably you need the shared_ptr (because if you could get away with a local object you wouldn't allocate one off of the heap), but you could even "cache" the result of the shared_ptr dereference:

```
void fn(shared_ptr< Dataset > pds)
{
   Dataset& ds = *pds;

   for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
   {
      f(ds);
      g(ds);
   }
}
```

...because even *pds requires hitting more memory than is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Did you mean to write f(ds) and g(ds)? I agree that caching the dereferenced value outside the loop would increase performance. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ha hah yes I did.  Edit should reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really know what you're doing. You've profiled your application, and you know exactly where cycles are being used. You understand that calling the constructor to a reference counting pointer is expensive only if you do it constantly.

The only heads up I can give you is: suppose inside function f(t *ptr), if you call another function that  uses shared pointers, and you do other(ptr) and other makes a shared pointer of the raw pointer. When that second shared pointers' reference count hits 0 then you have effectively deleted your object....even though you didn't want to. you said you used reference counting pointers a lot, so you have to watch out for corner cases like that.

<strike>EDIT:
You can make the destructor private, and only a friend of the shared pointer class, so that way the destructor can only be called by a shared pointer, then you're safe.</strike>  Doesn't prevent multiple deletions from shared pointers. As per comment from Mat.

Comment: No, you're not safer. If you have 2 differents pools of `shared_ptr` pointing to the same physical object, one pool will delete it before the other...