# Error passing shared_ptr<Derived>& as shared_ptr<Base>& without const

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, casting, shared-ptr

I got compile error when passing `shared_ptr<Derived>&` as `shared_ptr<Base>&`, see the below code and detailed question.

Note: this question is similar to "[`Passing shared_ptr<Derived> as shared_ptr<Base>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403490/passing-shared-ptrderived-as-shared-ptrbase)" but not duplicate.

```
#include <memory>
class TBase
{
public:
  virtual ~TBase() {}
};
class TDerived : public TBase
{
public:
  virtual ~TDerived() {}
};
void FooRef(std::shared_ptr<TBase>& b)
{
  // Do something
}

void FooConstRef(const std::shared_ptr<TBase>& b)
{
  // Do something
}

void FooSharePtr(std::shared_ptr<TBase> b)
{
  // Do something
}
int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<TDerived> d;
  FooRef(d);  // *1 Error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<TBase>&’ from expression of type ‘std::shared_ptr<TDerived>’
  FooConstRef(d); // *2 OK, just pass by const reference
  FooSharePtr(d); // *3 OK, construct a new shared_ptr<>
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled by `g++ -std=c++11 -o shared_ptr_pass_by_ref shared_ptr_pass_by_ref.cpp`

Env: Ubuntu 14.04, g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

**Detailed question:**
Why is it OK to pass by const reference (*2), but not OK to pass by reference (*1)?

Note: I know the best practice is to pass by const reference, but just want to know why the compile error occurs.

Comment: What if `FooRef` does `b.reset(new TBase)`? If the call were possible, you would end up with `std::shared_ptr<TDerived>` holding a `TBase*`. By the way, I suspect that `FooConstRef` call constructs a temporary that then binds to const reference; but temporaries can't bind to non-const ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to expect some kind of template covariance, whereby `AnyTemplateClass<Derived>` can bind to `AnyTemplateClass<Base>&`. Templates don't work this way. Generally, `AnyTemplateClass<Derived>` and `AnyTemplateClass<Base>` are two distinct, completely unrelated classes.

A specific template class may, or course, provide a relationship in some form. `shared_ptr<T>` in particular has a templated constructor accepting `shared_ptr<U>` for any `U` such that `U*` is convertible to `T*`.

`FooConstRef(d)` call works by constructing a temporary - effectively

```
shared_ptr<TBase> temp(d);
FooConstRef(temp);
```

But temporaries can't bind to non-const references, that's why `FooRef(d)` doesn't work in a similar way.

Comment: Great answer! But one more question, why the temporary of `shared_ptr<TBase>` can be created **effectively**? As long as it's a new `shared_ptr`, it still increase the `use_count`. Then is there any performance difference between `FooConstRef()` and `FooSharePtr()`, if we always pass shared_ptr<TDerived>?

Comment: "effectively" != "efficiently". In light of this fact, I'm not sure I quite understand your question. You seem to assume some meaning in my statement that I didn't place there.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, let me re-phrase: is there any performance difference between `FooConstRef()` and `FooSharePtr()`, if the passed parameter is `shared_ptr<TDerived>`? If I understand correctly, they have the same behavior, because both construct a temporary `shared_ptr<TBase>`, right?

Comment: No, I don't believe there's any difference, under given constraints.