# convert std::shared_ptr<Derived> to const shared_ptr<Base>&

Tags: c++

If I remember correctly (and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403490/passing-shared-ptrderived-as-shared-ptrbase)), `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` cannot be bind to `const std::shared_ptr<Base>&`. But when I tried the following code, it doesn't give me even any warnings.

```
#include <memory>
struct A{};
struct B:A{};

void Do(const std::shared_ptr<A>&){}

template<typename T>
struct C{};
void DoC(const C<A>&){}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>();
    Do(b); //accept ?
    /*following lines generate error
    C<B> c;
    DoC(c); //error
    //*/
}
```

compiler is `mingw g++ 5.3.0` with flag `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`

Same result with [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1289f7e6563781b) and many other online compiler.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure I understand. Then why `DoC(c)` gives me error?

Comment: @appleapple: Because `C<B>` doesn't know how to be converted to `C<A>` (where also `C<A>` doesn't know how to be constructed from a `C<B>`) they are unrelated whereas `shared_ptr<B>` and `shared_ptr<A>` are not unrelated.

Comment: @Pixelchemist can you tell me the difference between my question and the question I linked? I cannot find where I missed.

Comment: There is no difference when it comes to the `shared_ptr` example. I think @KerrekSB got you wrong here. The other question is quite misldeading since you actually *can* convert `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base> const&` (on any up to date compiler i tried) .

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Yes, true, the comment was too ambiguous anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` has [a constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that allows the conversion from `B` to `A`:

> *(from cppreference)*
>
> ```
> template< class Y > 
> shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r );
> ```
>
> 9) Constructs a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership of the object managed by `r`. If `r` manages no object, `*this` manages no object too. The template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`.

---

`DoC(c)` gives you an error because you haven't defined a constructor that does the conversion - a similar constructor will not be implicitly generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what already answered, I'd like to point out what passed to the function is a **temporary** `shared_ptr`. The code in question works because it's a **`const`**`shared_ptr&` which can bind a temporary.

---

```
#include <memory>
struct A{};
struct B:A{};

void Do(const std::shared_ptr<A>&){}
void DoNo(std::shared_ptr<A>&){}
void DoRvalue(std::shared_ptr<A>&&){}
void DoValue(std::shared_ptr<A>){}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>();
    Do(b); // a temporary is constructed and passed to Do 
    DoNo(b); // not work, temporary cannot bind to lvalue reference
    DoRvalue(b); // OK, temporary bind to rvalue reference
    DoValue(b); // OK
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sW8cf5ohe