# Why isn't shared_ptr to Derived implicitly converted to shared_ptr to Base

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, shared-ptr

I do not understand why in the following code, the `shared_ptr<Derived<int>>` isn't implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr<Base<int>>`:

```
#include <memory>
    
template <typename T>
class Base {
};
    
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
};
    
template <typename T>
T foo(std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>) {
    return T{};
}
    
void main() {
    foo(std::make_shared<Base<int>>());
    foo(std::make_shared<Derived<int>>());
}
```

I came across [convert std::shared_ptr<Derived> to const shared_ptr<Base>&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810500/), which seems related to me. Am I getting an error because I made a template of the function?

The error I get is:

> E0304 no instance of function template "foo" matches the argument list
>
> C2664 'std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> foo<int>(std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<Derived<int>>' to 'std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>'

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] and include that in your question? Compile that and include the exact error message it produces.

Comment: Yes, it's because of a template.

Comment: @Eljay It's implicitly convertible though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am not sure what more you want, i posted the entire code and the only error message i had from the compiler

Comment: @user this code is not compilable for other reasons. This is not minimal reproducible example'.

Comment: Does your compiler really refer to `Derived` as a type when it is actually a template? I.e. is it `shared_ptr<Derived>` or is it `shared_ptr<Derived<some type>>`?

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing unrelated typos, but please try and post the *exact* code you're compiling. `ctrl-c` `ctrl-v` is your friend.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it is `shared_ptr<Derived<int>>` returned from the `make_shared<Derived<int>>()`

Comment: I was referring to the error message. You know, that's why a [mcve] is required. That's why you should copy'n'paste the output. That's why I'm voting to close your question as off-topic currently.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I 've edited the question with copy pasted compiler messages, i didn't realize those would help. Are these what you were referring to ?

Comment: @user you need to use `&lt;` when quoting things that have `<...>` pairs in them, so they are not confused with HTML markup. I have edited the error messages for you so the `<` show correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the fact that `foo` is a template. Note, that everything works correctly if `foo` is not a template:

```
int foo(std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>) {
    return int{};
}
```

However, when `foo` is a template, the compiler first needs to instantiate `foo`, and it wants to be able to instantiate an exact match, since implicit conversions do not apply at this point. And this instantiation can not succeed, thus the error.

One way to workaround this issue would be to make `foo` a very greedy template, and then add additional constraints of convertibility. For example:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    using Type = T;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
};

template <typename T>
auto foo(T) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::shared_ptr<Base<typename T::element_type::Type>>>, typename T::element_type>
{    
    return typename T::element_type{};
}


int main() {
    foo(std::make_shared<Derived<int>>()); //OK
    foo(20); // error
}
```

Note, that I have added a `Type` member to the base class. This is not strictly necessary, but simplifies the code.

Comment: One thing you can do to allow the implicit conversion to take place is call `foo<int>(std::make_shared<Derived<Int>>());`, which will allow the implicit conversion to be useful.

Comment: Ok, but the template has already been instanciated with the first call in `main` and yet you are saying the call `foo(std::make_shared<Derived<int>>())` will not compile because it will rather find an exact match than take the instanciation created from `foo(std::make_shared<Base<int>>());` ?

Comment: @user templates are instantiated independently for each call to the template. If exact much has already been instantiated, it would be used (i.e. no new definition would be produced). The fact that template was instantiated for some code before doesn't mean that it would be blindly used - the process will be the same for the next attempt.

Comment: @SergeyA ok that makes sense, it feels stupid but this is actually what i couldn't figure out, thanks