# Why is shared_ptr counter incremented when passed as const reference to base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Why is `shared_ptr<drived>` counter incremented when I pass it to a function that expects a `const shared_ptr<base>&`?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403490/passing-shared-ptrderived-as-shared-ptrbase) one of the answers mentions:

```
shared_ptr<Base> and shared_ptr<Derived> are not covariant
```

I suspect that this is relevant to my question. What does it mean that they are not covariant?

Here is a code snippet to show case the scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

void f(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& x)
{
    std::cout << "in function expecting const shared_ptr<Base>& - Use count: " << x.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Base class" << std::endl;
    auto a = std::make_shared<Base>();
    std::cout << "Created shared_ptr:  Initial use count: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    f(a);

    std::cout << "------------------\nChild class" << std::endl;
    auto b = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    std::cout << "Created shared_ptr. Initial use count: " << b.use_count() << std::endl;
    f(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
>> g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
Base class
Created shared_ptr:  Initial use count: 1
in function expecting const shared_ptr<Base>& - Use count: 1
------------------
Child class
Created shared_ptr. Initial use count: 1
in function expecting const shared_ptr<Base>& - Use count: 2
```

Comment: For the second situation, the temporary (caused from slicing to the Base shared_ptr) being passed in will have incremented the use count.

Comment: @Eljay woudn't that be a different object/shared_ptr? How can the same use counter refer to the derived object and the slices object?

Comment: @Eljay There's no slicing involved here

Comment: The type is sliced (from `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>`), not the object.

Comment: Those types are unrelated so slicing can't happen (see my answer)

Comment: Is your Q specifically about an old version of C++?

Comment: @Eljay What do you mean by "sliced"?

Comment: @curiousguy The question is about C++11 facilities, but the example is also valid in C++17.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `shared_ptr<Derived>` is not a `shared_ptr<Base>`. They are completely different types.

In order to get a `shared_ptr<Base>` from a `shared_ptr<Derived>` you need to create one. The compiler can put in a call to the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) because it isn't marked explicit. This will increase the use count because they share ownership.

> `template< class Y > shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;`
>
> Constructs a shared_ptr which **shares ownership of the object managed by `r`**. If `r` manages no object, `*this` manages no object too. The template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not implicitly convertible to (until C++17) compatible with (since C++17) `T*`.

You can see for yourself that a new `shared_ptr` is created by changing `f()` to take a non-const reference. The compiler should give you an error because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. [See here](https://ideone.com/p88vON)

Comment: "A shared_ptr<Derived> is not a shared_ptr<Base>. They are completely different types.... This will increase the use count because they share ownership." How can two objects with two different types be owned by the same shared_ptr?

Comment: See my edit. The constructor only applies if a `Derived*` is implicitly convertible to a `Base*` (and they are). A `shared_ptr<Base>` sharing ownership to a `Derived` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @pooya13 The only thing that's owned by anything else is the single `Derived` object. There are two objects with two different types, the two `shared_ptr`'s, but they aren't owned by anything. Yes, two `shared_ptr`s of two different types can share ownership of the same object just as two `shared_ptr`s of the same type can.

Comment: What is an explicit copy ctor? What would that even means?

Comment: @curiousguy https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit. I suppose it's not a copy constructor because they're different types. I've edited my answer