# C++: Storing derived class's instance pointers in STL container of containers

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, c++14, liskov-substitution-principle

I read [Passing shared_ptr<Derived> as shared_ptr<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403490/passing-shared-ptrderived-as-shared-ptrbase) but that doesn't answer my question.

Suppose we have

```cpp
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};
```

I would like to create the following container: `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>>> _channels;`

I need to add instances as values with types `std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>>` and `std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>>`.

Unfortunately I'm unable to add instances with `Derived` type, but with type `Base` it's fine.

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
// works fine
/*
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Base>> _channels2;
    _channels2.emplace(std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>(3, std::make_shared<Derived>()));
    std::cout << "_channels2.size() = " << _channels2.size() << std::endl;
*/

// fails to compile
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>>> _channels;
    _channels.emplace(std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>>>(2, std::make_shared<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>>()));
    std::cout << "_channels.size() = " << _channels.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using C++14.

1. Am I understand well so the reason behind it fails to compile is because `std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>>` is not a subtype of `std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>>`? So polymorphism isn't available in this case.
2. Is there a workaround you can advise?

Thank you.

Comment: take two buses: one with only fathers in it, the second one with only their child. Does the first bus need to be the father of the second bus?

Comment: Well, yes, my main question was 
if a language feature exists like wildcard extends parameter in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something considering this works:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>> derived_map;
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> base_map(derived_map.begin(), derived_map.end());
```

thus you can write:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>> derived_map;
auto base_map = std::make_shared<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>>(derived_map->begin(), derived_map->end());
```

an so on... the drawback is that only base and derived are "shared", the maps are duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately iterating is rarely suits my classes.

Comment: there is no real iteration, I said so on because you used quite complicated structures, so you need to buid them up piece after piece