# Can an excessive use of smart pointers lead to an increase in system kernel calls?

Tags: c++, real-time, smart-pointers, pass-by-value, qnx

Can an excessive use of smart pointers (especially `shared_ptr`) cause an increase in kernel calls?

I am trying to optimize and simplify a real-time (QNX) codebase. One focus besides memory and realtime efficiency is reducing system kernel calls. I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844924/11671205) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502394/the-cost-of-passing-by-shared-ptr), so I have a basic understanding that overusing `shared_ptr`'s as call by value, might cause of some runtime performance issues. What I'm also curious about is whether this type of implementaions would also increase the kernel calls.

Please keep in mind that the `processSend` function is one of many functions that are called in a cycle and itself calls many other functions (like `Default`) in a similar way.

```
// getting called in every cycle (some milliseconds)
void signal::processSend(
    std::shared_ptr<const structA> readPtrA,
    std::shared_ptr<const structB> readPtrB,
    std::shared_ptr<const structC> readPtrC) {
        last_send_data = this->Default(readPtrA, readPtrB, readPtrC);
}

void signal::Default(
    std::shared_ptr<const structA> readPtrA,
    std::shared_ptr<const structB> readPtrB,
    std::shared_ptr<const structC> readPtrC) {
              // some value readings
}
```

Comment: This can easily depend on the OS and the underlying CPU architecture. Point is, that the management of the reference counter must be performed in a way that is multithreading-safe, which may require OS support. Can you look at the implementation?

Comment: The above code causes two copies of the `shared_ptr`. Whether those do kernel calls is less important than that you're doing a bunch of redundant work instead of just moving stuff. At the very least, `processSend` should move its arguments into `Default`.

Comment: `// some value readings`: This doesn't require taking (shared) ownership of the objects, so the parameters of that function shouldn't be `shared_ptr`s to begin with and can be raw pointers (or even references) instead. And then going backwards the same holds for `processSend` as well.

Comment: BTW: Assuming an atomic reference counter, you need to get exclusive (from a CPU point of view) access, increment/decrement the value and then push the value back so that every other CPU will only see that value. That doesn't necessarily require OS support, but is an expensive operation nonetheless. In particular, it can't be performed in a register or L1 cache alone.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Unfortunately I can't see the direct implementation but the whole thing is based on the QNX operating system. Is this information not sufficient?

Comment: Basic rule of thumb: don't use `std::shared_ptr` when `std::unique_ptr` will do.  `std::unique_ptr` is usually zero-overhead.

Comment: Which C++ standard library implementation are you using? If it's open source, it should be possible to find out. Otherwise, there must be a vendor which you could ask.

Comment: An excessive use of shared_ptr's can lead to circular dependencies and just "blindly" using them is IMO a design flaw. Use them with care, by design you should be able to know the lifecycle of objects. Often it is possible to create objects in main/factories and just keep references to them. The only time I really need/use share_ptr's is in multithreaded scenarios where not using shared ownership could lead to race conditions. Since the control block of a shared_ptr is threadsafe, yes its use can lead to extra synchronization calls.

Comment: How can you possibly be compiling code which instantiates the `shared_ptr` template and _not_ be able to just read the header?

Comment: If the CPU architecture supports atomic operations of sufficient size for the reference counter, then I don't see any reason that the implementation should need to rely on any kernel support. You can also just compile the function and look at the generated assembly. If there is a syscall, that should be obvious, and if a native atomic is used, it will be a simple atomic increment/decrement instruction, most likely inlined into the function.

Comment: @Useless, this is called type erasure. Basically, the control block is implemented in a way that doesn't depend on the template parameter. Effectively it's a `struct` with the refcount, a `void*` pointer to the object and a pointer to a function that destroys the object. All the type safety is umplemented in the template wrappers on top of it. Point is, that this doesn't have to be inline in the template code but could also in a binary-only distributable. And no, I haven't seen an implementation that actually does that, in case you're asking.

Comment: I know what type erasure is, but it's a good point I hadn't considered: I've also never seen an implementation use an opaque type here. Apart from anything else, it would prohibit the single-allocation optimization for `make_shared`.