# How do I check if System::Collections:ArrayList is empty / nullptr / null?

Tags: pointers, reference, c++-cli

I'd like to know how in C++/CLI it is possible to check whether an ArrayList is existent.

```
System::Collections::ArrayList %queue_tx
```

I tried `if ( nullptr != queue_tx ) { queue_tx.Add(msg); }` but that didn't work. I'm passing `queue_tx` as a parameter to a function and there's supposed to be the possibility of this parameter not being set (or being set to `nullptr`).

The compiler throws `'!=' : no conversion from 'System::Collections::ArrayList' to 'nullptr'`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` defines a reference variable this is why it cannot be null

if you would have declared the ArrayList like this:

```
System::Collections::ArrayList^ queue_tx
```

then your nullptr check would be possible and have a meaning

otherwise just use the `queue_tx.Count()` to check if the collection is empty

I would recommend going over:

[the difference between reference and pointer variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

[When to use a Reference VS Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite impossible for a `T%` to be null.

Comment: Yup, see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx, specifically "A tracking reference cannot be assigned null."