# Am I safely deleting a linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Just want to know if there are any flaws/inconsistencies/memory leaks in this implementation of deleting a linked list:

```
// Function to delete the entire linked list
void deleteList(Node** head) {

    Node* current = *head;
    Node* next;

    while (current != 0) {

        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;

    }

    *head = 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
struct Node {

    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int data) : data(data){}

};
```

Comment: It will be hard to answer this with certainty without the definition of `Node`

Comment: @TimothyJones: I'll raise your "hard" to "impossible".

Comment: You'll crash if `head` is invalid, otherwise looks ok (assuming `Node::next` is always properly initialized).

Comment: Destroying `int` obviously does not throw, but if you ever want generalize this to other types it would pay to be paranoid and update `head` before you start destroying nodes. You wouldn't want to leave an invalid pointer in `head` if the data destructor throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more C++ if you passed head pointer by reference, not by pointer:

```
void deleteList(Node * & head)
{
    // (...)

    head = nullptr; // NULL in C++ pre-11
}
```

Also, to keep code a little more tidy, you can move declaration of `next` inside the loop:

```
while (current != 0) 
{
    Node * next = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = next;
}
```

My only worries about memory leak would concern properly freeing node's contents, but since you store a simple int, there shouldn't be any problems there.

Assuming, that your list have valid pointers to nodes and that head pointer is valid too, everything else seems fine.

Comment: In general I had an "if current! = this" before deleting and mark an error in case.

Comment: What is the advantage to using the reference instead of the pointer?

Comment: @RSinghS You cannot pass a null object, cannot pass immediate value (lvalue) and a lot more explicitly inform your source code reader, that you want to modify passed variable (it is not *that* obvious in case of a pointer). Read further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers