# Difference b/n objects, Reference, Pointers

Tags: c#, c++, c, pointers

I started programming in c, and then worked little bit on Java and c#.

- So my understanding of an object(instance of a class) is that its like a pointer to the instance stored in memory(may be which points to the first memory cell of the whole instance...similar to struct or array A[] has its initial address stored in A).

Is my above understanding correct?

- Recently I have been going through differences b/n reference and
  pointer in c++. This is where it gets more confusing as I read
  more.Like:

  [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

  [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c#)

Reading from the above I understand both are same except references gaurds you by not taking null.

One point I don't get is they say:
Pointer variable can be reassigned after initializing, but reference variable cannot be.But I tested this scenario and compiler allows me to re-assign, does it depend on the compiler??.
If at all it cannot be reassigned a different value, what is the use of 'pass by ref' at all(in c++)?

Also can someone suggest a reliable and cool online source for c++, like msdn for c#

And also it would be nice if there is an easy way to see the address stored in a reference variable in c++

Comment: The reference itself can't refer to a new variable. And C# has passing by reference (I assume you mean `ref`) because value types are passed by value. Java has these as well (the primitives), but does not let you create your own like C# does (albeit limited). C++ does passing by value by default.

Comment: A great, up to date reference for C++ is http://cppreference.com.

Comment: I find http://www.cplusplus.com/ on google a lot.. is it good enough

Comment: Greg Hewgill answered the question in his comments. Thanks to him again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your understanding is mostly correct.

Regarding your final question, in C++ you can change what a pointer points to by giving it a new value:

```
int a, b;
int *p = &a;
p = &b;
```

However, you can't do the same with references:

```
int a, b;
int &r = a;
// ??? no syntax to make r refer to b at this point
```

Comment: what happens if you do r = b;

Comment: If you do `r = b;`, then the value of `b` gets assigned to `a`. The reference `r` still refers to `a`.

Comment: now I get it!!. Thankyou so much thats all I wanted :). I think this post is highly redundant is it ok if I delete it? or it might be useful for others?

Comment: Well you can't delete it now, it has answers. I think it's fine.

Comment: so even if a and b were objects. After we change r from a to b now both a and b point to same instance(b's)..but r still points to a's address correct?

Comment: Now you've lost me. I don't understand what you mean by "change `r` from `a` to `b`"

Comment: I meant int &r = a; r =b;

Comment: In that case, the effect is identical to `a = b;`. If `a` and `b` are pointers to something *else*, then yes, you would then have both pointing to the same place. But that doesn't happen with integers as in the example above.

Comment: yeah, thats why I said objects

Comment: So in case of integers(primitive types) the value gets copied because references are stored in the same memory cell as value is?

Comment: In C++, objects don't imply pointers and pointers don't imply objects. Gotta be specific!

Comment: It's not because of memory cells, but rather the C++ language specification says that is what happens.

Comment: hmmm. I got this cell thing from C++ FAQ

Answer (score 0):

> If so why do c# has pass by reference

C# isn't pass by reference.. it is pass-by-value (unless explicitly using `ref`). The *value* of the reference is copied.

You can think of references as pointers.. with type safety. The underlying implementation detail is of little consequence (although, as I understand it, they currently are a wrapper around a pointer.. but they may not always be).

> Pointer variable can be reassigned after initializing, but reference variable cannot be.But I tested this scenario and compiler allows me to re-assign,

There is no restriction on re-assigning a reference like you describe. A new reference will be copied over the top of the existing one. So I'm not sure I understand that issue.

I think your understanding of the above is skewed when passing references through methods. Here is an example:

```
public class Customer {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public static void Main() {
    var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Simon" };
    Example(customer);
    Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
}

public static void Example(Customer customer) {
    customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "CHANGED" };
}
```

([Working example here](http://ideone.com/hSQPjG))

What would this print? The answer is "Simon". The reference was copied into the function. You've re-assigned the local reference. When exiting.. the original reference remains unchanged.

How do you "fix" that? (Not that I would expect the below behaviour..) .. you pass by ref explicitly:

```
public class Customer {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public static void Main() {
    var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Simon" };
    Example(ref customer); // By ref
    Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
}

public static void Example(ref Customer customer) { // By ref
    customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "CHANGED" };
}
```

([Working sample here](http://ideone.com/1P1GTW))

This prints "CHANGED", since the explicit pass-by-ref has been requested by the user of the `ref` keyword.

Comment: I know c# is pass by value, what I meant was, what is purpose of having pass by ref..the ref keyword. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: See my update with examples (and IDEOne links to running samples).

Comment: @Ojay I am unsure how that counters my statement. The MSDN sample clearly demonstrates pass-by-value of a reference.