# The simplest way to create a member function returning reference to object

Tags: c++, class

I created a member function that returning reference to object.

I can do it like:

```
class Foo {
  Foo &ref(){
    return *this;
  }
}
```

`ref` returning object by look up `this` pointer.

Is there any way else to return object without using `this`?

**EXPLAIN the reason:**

The reason I don't want to use `this` is: the pointer occupy 4B in stack whereas the reference share the same memory

Comment: What could possibly be simpler than `return *this;`?

Comment: I need some operator (`<<` for example) that returing object

Comment: Are you saying that you're not allowed to use `this`?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use `this`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why not? It's like saying you want to add two integers without using `+`.

Comment: I wonder why in c++ class, we have `this` as a pointer but have not anything else as a reference, and why `this` must be pointer

Comment: @DMaster Is your real question "why is `this` a pointer and not a reference"?

Comment: Without using this? No! Without using this in that particular function? Yes, but it makes things more complicated, so I see no reason to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't like `this` *and* you don't want to dereference any pointers. How about:

```
class Foo {
  private:
    int dummy;
  public:
    Foo& ref() {
        return reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(dummy);
    }
};
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Foo>::value,
              "Foo must be standard-layout!");
```

Because `Foo` is a standard-layout class and `dummy` is its first non-static data member and there are no base classes, the address of `dummy` is the same as that of the containing `Foo`.

Needless to say, this is a very silly way to return a reference to an object and I can't see any possible justification for doing it this way. Not wanting to write `return *this;` is like wanting to add two integers without using `+`. It just makes no sense at all.

Comment: anyway, thank you. The reason I don't want to use `this` is: the pointer occupy 4B in stack whereas the reference share the same memory

Comment: @DMaster That's simply not right. The generated machine code will usually have to store the address of a reference somewhere like it stores a pointer's value. In some cases a reference can be optimized out, but the same is true for pointers.

Comment: @DMaster You can find questions like that on this site, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/c-when-to-use-references-vs-pointers