# Can I use something other than dynamic_cast in this design?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, casting, dynamic-cast

In our system, we have

- multiple deviceTypes
- each deviceType can have a different configuration type
- each deviceType will be a library of its own

I'm in a situation where I am forced to use dynamic_cast. I'm wondering if there is a better way to design this ?

what I have is:

```
// in common code
class Config {public: virtual ~Config(){} }; 

    class Device {
     protected:
        Config* devConfig;
    protected:
        virtual void createDevConfig() = 0;
    public:
        virtual void display() = 0;
    };

    // Device specific Code
    class A0Device : public Device {
    protected:
        virtual void createDevConfig() { this->devConfig = new A0Config(); }
    public:
        A0Device() { this->createDevConfig(); }

        virtual void display(){
        A0Config* config = dynamic_cast<A0Config*>(this->devConfig);

        if(!config) std::cout << "Null object\n";

        }
    };

    class A0Config : public Config {};

    int main() {
        Device* dev = new A0Device();
        dev->display();
        return 0;
    }
```

Essentially `A0Device` has its own config type: `A0Config`, which is composed of other members. A0Device has `devConfig` defined as `Config*` in base class. In `A0Device::display()` - I need to access the devConfig object (as `A0Config` type). The `virtual createDevConfig()` ensures the config object will always be of type `A0Config` in `A0Device` => Is it safe to use dynamic_cast here ? Is there a better way of designing this ?

Comment: Why does A0Device need a base class?

Comment: If you haven't heard of [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B), take a look. That's another possible solution.

Comment: You could move the `devConfig` field into `A0Device`, then change the type to `A0Config*` since it's now specific to `A0Device`s only.

Comment: @NeilKirk SDK functions entirely on device and the knowledge of A0Device and other deviceTypes are completely abstracted in their own libraries

Comment: Device should call a virtual function on Config. Or Config pointer should be moved to A0Device. You could make derived device a template with the config as the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you can support the extra (minimal in general-purpose systems, enormous in real-time/embedded systems) runtime overhead, you can use `dynamic_cast<>` safely.

However, you must be aware of this "small" detail. Given the expression `dynamic_cast<T*>(expr)`, whenever the dynamic type of `*expr` is *neither* `T` or a subclass of `T`, **the expression evalutates to the null pointer, `nullptr`**. And, of course, **dereferencing `nullptr` invokes undefined behaviour, and will cause a crash on most platforms**.

However, it's probably not worth it checking for `nullptr` **if, ando only if, you know your code shall crash on such a situation**.

Because C++ is a bowl with both soup and ice cream, potatoes and coffee, and of course, each idea that came through Stroustrup's/the C++ commitee's ears/mind, there are several alternatives:

- A *downcasting* `static_cast<T*>(expr)`, although this has the same issues as casting something to something else that it isn't.
- For C people who found it "necessary", `reinterpret_cast<T*>(expr)` is not necessary in this but it's there.
- If you **both** think that something is engineeringly-perfect if it works, and you know *all* the types that the object may have at runtime in a single place, you can use a `enum for the type` with `union for holding the data` with `placement new` with `explicit destructor calls` supercombo.
- If data stuff is involved in the problem, you can have something like `virtual Config &getConfig() = 0` in the Base, and something like `ABC123Config config; Config &getConfig { return this->config; }` in the Derived.
- ***For crazyies like me only***: Use a C-style/constructor-style cast.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @brainydexter: Do you mean the *if that stuff is involved...* point?

Comment: Yes : `virtual Config &getConfig() = 0 in the Base, `

Comment: Also, in my question, the dynamic casting will not happen frequently, init time perhaps - so I don't think runtime expense will be a problem. As a design, do you think there is a problem here ?

Comment: The expression `virtual Config &getConfig() = 0` declares a [pure virtual function](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/pure-virtual-function/) named `getConfig` that returns a `Config&` (and thus, the return value can reference a given `Derived` object as I said you in another comment). The `virtual` specifier tells the compiler that the dynamic type of the object shall be queried whenever calling the function through a `Base&` or `Base*`. By default, a base class defines a function to be called if the real object's type doesn't overload the function. (To be continued...)

Comment: @brainydexter: Sorry, I had to cut the commnet in two due to it's length. **Continuation**: The `= 0` specifier (called the *pure specifier*), marks the virtual function as *pure*. A pure virtual function does *not* have a default to call if the function isn't overloaded. Thus, a class containing a pure virtual function cannot be instantiated (it would be catastrophic!), and is said to be *abstract*. In the inheritance tree, all subclasses of an abstract `Base` will be implicitly abstract until all the pure virtual functions get fully implemented by a given subclass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88049/discussion-between-brainydexter-and-kemyland).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a pure virtual function in the base which returns a `Config` pointer or reference (which I would prefer unless you need a pointer), then have the storage in the derived classes. This question/answers cover the differences between pointers and references: [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

The advantage of this design is that anything in the base that needs a `Config` can use `getConfig`, while anything that needs to use the derived class can without casting. Plus you don't need to call `new` and `delete`.

```
class Device {
   protected:
      virtual Config& getConfig() = 0;
   ...
};

class A0Device {
public:
   ...
   Config& getConfig() {return config;}
   ...
private:
   A0Config config;
};
```

Comment: When A0Device getconfig is called, you will get a config object and not A0Config type -- correct?

Comment: @brainydexter: Both pointers and references to any `Base` may actually point to/reference a given `Derived` object.

Comment: ok but what does a reference buy me here instead of using a pointer ? This config will contain a lot of other structs which will point to HUGE arrays. Hence, I was leaning towards using pointers

Comment: @brainydexter: A reference to `T` is basically a constant pointer to `T` which implicitly dereferences the object whenever used. For the **huge** data structures you described, I'll prefer pointers all day long. You may read the advantages of references vs pointers and viceversa [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers).

Comment: @brainydexter, I prefer references to objects rather than pointers if you aren't dynamically selecting an object as it is easier to read (no messy dereferences when accessing), makes sure that you can't make a mistake like incrementing the pointer (unless you intentionally do something like take the address, but you can't prevent people from intentionally misusing things), and gives more information than a pointer ('This is the thing you want' rather than 'This is one of potentially many things')

Comment: @brainydexter, you can think of references being  const pointers, or pointers that you can't change (T* const). Don't confuse that with pointers to const objects where you can change what the pointer points to, but not the object pointed to (const T*). Any benefits that you get from pointers you also get with references. Except for being able to select an arbitrary object.

Comment: got it. Thanks @DominicMcDonnell

Comment: Thanks @KemyLand. I'll use that link in my answer.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell: No problem :).

Comment: @brainydexter, I just added to my answer to explain why I would solve your problem this way, if you hadn't figured it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks @DominicMcDonnell : Yes, I see the benefit. I will most likely go this way, but I will still need to use dynamic_cast. In my codebase, Device has blocks (as member pointers) and the blocks will not have a reference to device object. within a block, I get reference to device::config like this: `DeviceMgr::instance()->getDevice(deviceId)->getConfig()` => depending on deviceType the correct configType will be returned

Answer (score 0):

[Not sure, if I'm missing something here, but it more or less sounds like a design-smell]

Why can't `A0Config` aggregate `Config`?

Quite often, hitting upon `dynamic_cast` is a clue that something is not right in terms of establishing **IS-A** relationship. In this case `A0Config`provides some functionality (`getA()`) which doesn't fit into its base class `Config`, perhaps it is violating [LSP-Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) thereby violating **strong IS-A**.

Nevertheless, [If a class relationship can be expressed in more than one way, use the weakest relationship that's practical – Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm)

... and Sean Parent goes to this extent. [Inheritance is the base class of evil](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil)