# Difference between reference and non-reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference

Lets say we have the following code that doesn't use references:

```
int val = 5;
int val2 = func(val);

int func(int v) {
   return v * v;
}
```

Would the code be better with using references? I understand the difference between pointers and references, but not when to use references as opposed to not use them.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense, it's like 'should I swim in the pool or should I take a cup of coffee. Different scenarios call for different techniques.

Comment: Yes but what is the difference? When do you want to use references and when are they not neccessary?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).  Also with something like an int passing by reference or value will normally not make a difference.