# C pointers and references

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I would like to know what's really happening calling & and * in C.
Is that it costs a lot of resources? Should I call `&` each time I wanna get an adress of a same given variable or keep it in memory i.e in a cache variable. Same for * i.e when I wanna get a pointer value ?

**Example**

```
void        bar(char *str)
{
    check_one(*str)
    check_two(*str)

    //... Could be replaced by

    char    c = *str;

    check_one(c);
    check_two(c);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly? A compiler will most likely optimize the first form into the second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use References vs. Pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Comment: @EliSadoff no this is C not C++

Comment: It costs nearly nothing, so stop worrying about it and concentrate on the logic.

Comment: @Eli this is C not C++, C doesn't have reference type

Comment: @StoryTeller it can't: `check_one` might end up modifying the char pointed to by `str`.

Comment: @Danh C doesn't have passing by reference though.

Comment: @Quentin, you mean the `char` passed by value?

Comment: @Danh, when did I say *anything* about references?

Comment: ofc it does mean check_one(const char c);

Comment: @StoryTeller suppose that `str` points at some global `char` variable, that is modified by `check_one`. Devious, but possible.

Comment: @EliSadoff yes, but It is not duplicate with that question right.  I replied to Story's comment above that C doesn't have reference type

Comment: @Quentin if the function signature is `check_one(char c)` (note there is no star there), I fail to see how that's possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm sorry, had wanted to tag Eli

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I think you have the OP confused with me

Comment: I tagged this as a duplicate because it seemed that despite being tagged as C it was about C++ mostly because references don't exist within C.

Comment: @Romain-p are you using C or C++? This question is relatively confusing if it's about C because references don't exist in C.

Comment: @StoryTeller `char g = 'a'; void check_one(char c) { g = 'b'; } /* ... */ bar(&g);` -- in this case, `check_two` will receive `'b'`, not `'a'`.

Comment: yea but this sign '&' means reference for me i.e the address

Comment: @Romain-p Reference != address.

Comment: @EliSadoff, just because C++ uses "reference" as a technical term, doesn't mean the rest of the English speaking world is banned from using it as colloquial for pass-by-pointer. Since this question isn't tagged C++, there is no confusion

Comment: @Quentin, got ya. And I am again reminded of the evil that is globals

Comment: aight sorry! i was meaning the adress so! Yet, we call *var dereference

Comment: @EliSadoff Well, it is possible to de-reference in C, there's an operator for that... It'd be rather strange to de-reference a non-reference, now wouldn't it. Therefore it follows, that C must be able to have references ;-)

Comment: @hyde I think the official name is "Indirection". No "de-reference" operator in the C standard.

Comment: okay! so much vocabulary

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, for `*` yeah, but if wikipedia is correct, `->` is called struct *dereference* operator (didn't check the standard text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know what's really happening calling & and * in C.

There's no such thing as "calling" `&` or `*`. They are the address operator, or the dereference operator, and instruct the compiler to work with the address of an object, or with the object that a pointer points to, respectively.

And C is not C++, so there's no references; I think you just misused that word in your question's title.

In most cases, that's basically two ways to look at the same thing.

Usually, you'll use `&` when you actually want the address of an object. Since the compiler needs to handle objects in memory with their address anyway, there's no overhead.

For the specific implications of using the operators, you'll have to look at the assembler  your compiler generates.

---

Example: consider this trivial code, disassembled via [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void check_one(char c)
{
    if(c == 'x')
        exit(0);
}

void check_two(char c)
{
    if(c == 'X')
        exit(1);
}

void foo(char *str)
{
    check_one(*str);
    check_two(*str);
}

void bar(char *str)
{
    char c = *str;
    check_one(c);
    check_two(c);
}

int main()
{
    char msg[] = "something";
    foo(msg);
    bar(msg);
}
```

The compiler output can far *wildly* depending on the vendor and optimization settings.

**clang 3.8 using -O2**

```
check_one(char):                          # @check_one(char)
        movzx   eax, dil
        cmp     eax, 120
        je      .LBB0_2
        ret
.LBB0_2:
        push    rax
        xor     edi, edi
        call    exit

check_two(char):                          # @check_two(char)
        movzx   eax, dil
        cmp     eax, 88
        je      .LBB1_2
        ret
.LBB1_2:
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit

foo(char*):                               # @foo(char*)
        push    rax
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rdi]
        cmp     eax, 88
        je      .LBB2_3
        movzx   eax, al
        cmp     eax, 120
        je      .LBB2_2
        pop     rax
        ret
.LBB2_3:
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit
.LBB2_2:
        xor     edi, edi
        call    exit

bar(char*):                               # @bar(char*)
        push    rax
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rdi]
        cmp     eax, 88
        je      .LBB3_3
        movzx   eax, al
        cmp     eax, 120
        je      .LBB3_2
        pop     rax
        ret
.LBB3_3:
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit
.LBB3_2:
        xor     edi, edi
        call    exit

main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Notice that `foo` and `bar` are *identical*. Do other compilers do something similar? Well...

**gcc x64 5.4 using -O2**

```
check_one(char):
        cmp     dil, 120
        je      .L6
        rep ret
.L6:
        push    rax
        xor     edi, edi
        call    exit
check_two(char):
        cmp     dil, 88
        je      .L11
        rep ret
.L11:
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit
bar(char*):
        sub     rsp, 8
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        cmp     al, 120
        je      .L16
        cmp     al, 88
        je      .L17
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L16:
        xor     edi, edi
        call    exit
.L17:
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit
foo(char*):
        jmp     bar(char*)
main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        movabs  rax, 7956005065853857651
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     eax, 103
        mov     WORD PTR [rsp+8], ax
        call    bar(char*)
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    bar(char*)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

Well, if there were any doubt `foo` and `bar` are equivalent, a least by the compiler, I think this:

```
foo(char*):
        jmp     bar(char*)
```

is a strong argument they indeed *are*.

Comment: Okay but imagine, I have a var: `char c = 'a'`. What's going on if I do: `&&c`

Comment: `&c` gives me the adress of C and `&&c` should create a new memory case containing the adress of the adress of the char

Comment: @Romain-p that's not true. `&c` is just a temporary value. Whether or not it gets its own memory depends on what you do with it. You can't `&&c`, since `&c` itself doesn't have an address. Did you try compiling that code?

Comment: @Romain-p That is only valid in C++ and that results in a rvalue-reference in c++11 onwards or error in pre c++11

Comment: Of course, that's why I write "should", cause & should give me an adress of a given var, and it doesnt work in some cases

Comment: @Romain-p: what's the address of an address?

Comment: @Romain-p what you think "should" be the case for C doesn't make any difference, to be honest :) In my world, `&(&c)` *should* not work (and see, it doesn't work) in C because `&c` is an rvalue, and thus simply doesn't have an address, simple as that.

Comment: @John Bode: Given `char **var`, `var[0] (=) *var` returns me an address (pointer) pointing on the memory case containing my char. `**var (=) var[0][0]` should also return me a char. So I thought it works in the other sens i.e given `char c`, `&c` should give me the address of my char c. And `&(&c)` could create a new pointer

Comment: @Romain-p: You can obtain the address of an *object* that contains a pointer value, but you cannot obtain the address *of an address*.  `&(&c)` can't work in C, not only because the operation is nonsensical, but because the operand of unary `&` must be an *lvalue* (an expression that refers to an object such that the object may be read and/or modifed); however, the *result* of using the unary `&` operator is *not* an lvalue - it doesn't refer to an object, it's just a value (just like you can't assign to a new value to the result of `1+2`).

Answer (score 2):

In C, there's no runtime cost associated with either the unary `&` or `*` operators; both are evaluated at compile time.  So there's no difference in runtime between

```
check_one(*str)
check_two(*str)
```

and

```
 char c = *str;
 check_one( c );
 check_two( c );
```

ignoring the overhead of the assignment.

That's not necessarily true in C++, since you can overload those operators.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;**

If you are programming in C, then the `&` operator is used to obtain the address of a variable and `*` is used to get the value of that variable, given it's address.

---

This is also the reason why in C, when you pass a string to a function, you must state the length of the string otherwise, if someone unfamiliar with your logic sees the function signature, they could not tell if the function is called as `bar(&some_char)` or `bar(some_cstr)`.

To conclude, if you have a variable `x` of type `someType`, then `&x` will result in `someType* addressOfX` and `*addressOfX` will result in giving the value of `x`. Functions in C only take pointers as parameters, i.e. you cannot create a function where the parameter type is `&x` or `&&x`

Also your examples can be rewritten as:

```
check_one(str[0])
check_two(str[0])
```

Comment: Given `char **var`, `var[0] (=) *var` returns me an address (pointer) pointing on the memory case containing my char. `**var (=) var[0][0]` should also return me a char. So I thought it works in the other sens i.e given `char c`, `&c` should give me the address of my char c. And &(&c) could create a new pointer pointing on my first pointer pointing on my char

Comment: @Romain-p it still works that way, the only problem is that you have to split it into multiple statements for it to work. So `char *p = &c`, then `char **pp = &p`. C limits you to only using one `&` operator because `&c` will produce an rvalue, this means it produces a variable which does not have an address, so doing `&&c` is like trying to take the address of a variable which does not have an address...whaaa?? Stop it

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in x86 and x64 your variables are stored in memory (if not stated with `register` keyword) and accessed by pointers.
`const int foo = 5` equal to `foo dd 5` and `check_one(*foo)` equal to `push dword [foo]; call check_one`.

If you create additional variable `c`, then it looks like:

```
c resd 1
...
mov eax, [foo]
mov dword [c], eax ; Variable foo just copied to c
push dword [c]
call check_one
```

And nothing changed, except additional copying and memory allocation.
I think that compiler's optimizer deals with it and makes both cases as fast as it is possible. So you can use more readable variant.