# C++ why the type of parameter of atomic_load is pointer instead of reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

I agree the answer in [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers).
But, I am wondering why C++ defines atomic_load as

```
template<class T>
T atomic_load(const std::atomic<T> *obj) noexcept;
                                   ^
```

instead of

```
template<class T>
T atomic_load(const std::atomic<T> &obj) noexcept;
                                   ^
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Most likely for uniformity with the [equivalent C interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_load).

Comment: @WhiZTiM But, std::atomic is a class template, why does it require to consistent with C?

Comment: It is not strictly required, it is a convenience for the programmer who doesn't have to remember yet another pointless difference. You just need to remember that `atomic_load` takes a pointer, regardless of what base type exactly you are passing.

Answer (score 10):

The reason why we have these free function templates at all is source compatibility with C11:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <atomic>
#define _Atomic(X) std::atomic<X>
#else
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif

_Atomic(int) c;

int get_c(void) { 
    return atomic_load(&c); 
}
```

C doesn't have references.

If you don't need that, then `c.load()` or the implicit conversion to `T` will work just fine. Just forget that the free function ever existed.

(This is also why the `memory_order` version of the free function template is called `atomic_load_explicit`: `_Generic`-powered macros in C can handle varying argument types, but not varying arity.)