# push_back a class object using vector.

Tags: c++, vector

How to add object of class to vector in another class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class info{
    private: 
        int id;
        string name;
    public:
        info(int extId, string extName) {
            this->id = extId;
            this->name = extName;
        }
};

class db {
    private:
        vector<info> infoVector;
    public:
        void pushData(info * data) {
            this->infoVector.push_back(&data);
        }
};

int main(){ 
    info * testData = new info(123, "nice"); 

    db database;
    database.pushData(testData);    

    return 0;
}
```

I am creating a object of `info` class. The object contains one `int` and one `string` variables. Then I am creating `db` object and I am passing there a `testData` object.

I got error message while building project.

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void db::pushData(info*)’:
main.cpp:23:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<info>::push_back(info*&)’
             this->infoVector.push_back(data);
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = info; _Alloc = std::allocator<info>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = info]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘info*’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const info&}’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's in the error message "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘info*’ to ... const info&". You have `vector<info> infoVector;` which accepts `info` types but you're trying to give it a `info*` type.

Comment: Why do you use new?

Comment: It's a bit worse than what James points out. `pushData` takes a pointer and the address of that pointer, a temporary local to the function, is passed to `push_back`.  This does not line up with the given error messages, so I think this is the result of some misfires while debugging. Helpful reading: [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the address of an `info *` type to `vector<info>::push_back`, which [only accepts types of `const info &` or `info &&`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).  Try using the [dereference operator `*` instead of the address-of operator `&`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) when you call `push_back`:

```
this->infoVector.push_back(*data);
```

This isn't a great way to use pointers, however, and could lead to memory leakage or segfaults if `data` is removed from the vector or if it is deleted.  It is better for the `vector` to own its members, so you might consider doing this instead:

```
class db {
    private:
    vector<info> infoVector;
    public:
    void pushData(info data) {            // note: not a pointer
        this->infoVector.push_back(data); // note: not address-of
    }
};

int main(){ 
    info testData(123, "nice"); // note: not a pointer
    db database;
    database.pushData(testData);
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you really want `infoVector` to contain pointers, declare it as:

```
std::vector<info*> infoVector;
```

Then remove the address-to operator.

P.S., [avoid `using namespace std` whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)!

Comment: `this->infoVector.push_back(*data);` would probably result in memory leakage.

Comment: Agreed--code and answer updated to make note of this.

Comment: both options works! I mean that I can add the new object to vector.  Now I have  the second problem. I don't know how to print the object from the vector. I have tried this: 
 `void outPutData() {
            cout << this->infoVector.back();
}`
Then I used this method like that:  `database.outPutData()`
I does not work. In next step I have created function `getId()` in `info class`. Then in modified `outPutData()` method like that:
`cout << this -> infoVector[0].getId();` 

I got the error: 
`invalid use of non-static member function`

Is there any way to print the values?

Comment: It's difficult to know how to help without seeing the full class definitions you are trying.  If an answer posted here is sufficient for your original question, I would suggest accepting one as an answer and asking a new question concerning this new problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have `vector<info>` and you want to put `info *`, try to do:

```
int main(){ 
    info testData(123, "nice"); 

    db database;
    database.pushData(testData);    

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the right direction, but incomplete. `pushData` also needs to be modified. You should show that as well.