# Eclipse C++ String as function parameter

Tags: c++, string, function, mingw

I am having a problem with an error function which' purpose it is to check a variable and in a certain case tell me the variables name and its value.

I want to give the value as well as the name (as a string) to the function but I am having problems declaring a string somehow (Eclipse MinGW C++).

If anyone could point me to my mistake or show me a workaround that would be great!

This is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *ierr;

std::string(varname); //problem here, doesnt recognize the string

void error(double varvalue, std::string varname)
 {
        if (varvalue == 0 ) {
            *ierr = 11;
            cout << "Error: " << varname << " has an invalid value (equal 0)";
            cout << "Error number " << *ierr << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (varvalue < 0 ) {
            *ierr = 10;
            cout << "Error: " << varname << " has an invalid value (" << varvalue << " , smaller 0)";
            cout << "Error number: " << *ierr << endl;
            return;
        }
 }

int main() {
    int Par = 0;
    error(Par,"Par"); //test variable
}
```

Comment: Which errors do you get? What purpose is `std::string(varname);` for at all?

Comment: Where is `varname` defined?

Comment: The thing is I dont get a compiling error or anything similar. When I try to compile it at the point of output I get a Windows error: "Testing.dll has stopped working" and it closes.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `std::string(varname);`? Why don't you just remove it?

Comment: std::string(varname);  is the definition. I want to declare varname as a string which gives a variable name to the function.

Comment: A bigger problem is that you're seg faulting all over the place because of `int *ierr`

Comment: Yeah, as GKE points out, the pointer ierr is uninitialized and that's what is giving you trouble. You should replace that line with
int *ierr = new int(0);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Ok I changed *ierr to ierr and now the program is actually working. Thanks. Thought the problem was somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not correctly define a string value. The syntax is incorrect. On a more serious note, you declare an uninitialized pointer `*ierr` and it's causing seg faults at run-time.

> I am having a problem with an error function which' purpose it is to check a variable and in a certain case tell me the variables name and its value.

The code below will do that for you but it's important to understand [when to use pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Furthermore you should probably read up a little on [strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and get familiar with what a string definition, copy, initialization, etc, look like.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void error(double varvalue, std::string varname)
 {

        if (varvalue == 0 ) { //if varvalue is equal to 0

            cout << "Error: " << varname << " has an invalid value (equal 0)";
            cout << "Error number " << varvalue << endl;
            return;
        }

        if (varvalue < 0 ) { //if varvalue is less than 0

            cout << "Error: " << varname << " has an invalid value (" << varvalue << " , smaller 0)";
            cout << "Error number: " << varvalue << endl;
            return;
        }

        if (varvalue > 0) { //if varvlue is greater than 0

            cout<<varname<<" has value: "<<varvalue<<endl;

        }
 }

int main() {

    int Par = 10; // Set initial Par value to 10

    error(Par,"Par"); //test variable

}
```

Comment: Thanks, *ierr was my problem. Changed it to ierr and now its working fine. I copied that variable from a older program which I should have checked better.