# C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type for parent and child classes

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes: `Parent` and `Child`.

```
class Child : public Parent {...};
```

I define a variable

```
vector<Parent*> v;
```

`v` has a couple of pointer instances of `Child` class.

I have a function:

```
void myFunc(Child *c) {...}
```

When I call `myFunc(v[1])`, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type "Parent*" is incompatible with parameter of type `Child*`.
```

I thought that the inheritance should work here without a problem, but it doesn't. Could anyone help?

Comment: You thought wrong, it works without problem the other way around.

Comment: Public inheritance in C++ expresses 'IS-A' principle, where every child is a parent. But it doesn't work the other way around, i.e. a parent is not a child!

Comment: [Wiki page on the is-a relationship.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) Unrelated to your problem here but important in general is the Liskov Substitution Principle. I strongly recommend reading the section on it as well.

Comment: There must be a dup somewhere but cannot find a good one

Comment: @Slava, that's the problem, I didn't find any dups :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards! The problem being that in C++, the parent-child relationship is one way. Or in other words it's an *IS-A* relationship.

Basically this means that while children classes can take place of parents, i.e. you can pass a `sedan` to an `automobile` vector, you can't go backwards. Because not every `automobile` is a `sedan`.

Your function definition should be `void myFunc(Child *c) {...}` if you ONLY want to take the child class, but if you want to take ANY child of the parent, or the parent itself, then do it like: `void myFunc(Parent *p) {...}` instead.

Also as a small sidenote, I suggest using references instead of pointers whenever possible. [See here for more discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058373/7859598)

*Addendum:*

> I want to use function overloading to define different behaviour for different types of Childs for myFunc. Any Idea how I can do this?

In order to accomplish this you can use templates and use specialization like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class automobile {

};

class sedan : public automobile {

};

template <typename T> 
void foo(T& t) { 
  std::cout << "An automobile!" << std::endl;
}

template <> 
void foo<sedan>(sedan& t) { 
  std::cout << "A sedan!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  automobile a;
  sedan s;
  foo<automobile>(a);
  foo<sedan>(s);
}
```

And the output as expected is:

```
An automobile!
A sedan!
```

Comment: I want to use function overloading to define different behaviour for different types of `Child`s for `myFunc`. Any Idea how I can do this?

Comment: You have an IS-A relationship with a sedan. You are a sedan.

Comment: @DimaDz If I understood the question correctly, I edited the answer to show how you can do that with templates

Comment: @DimaDz updated code to be more indicative of question

Comment: @DimaDz Alternative to templates: If each child has different behaviour, take advantage of polymporphism and build the function into the classes with a `virtual` method. Example: https://ideone.com/s7AAYW

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, child class have "is a" relationship with his parent, but the opposite is false.
It's logical , for example parent class is human and child class is men , we can say men is human , but human is men it's not true.