# sorting in ascending order using bubble sort with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have to print pointer parameters in ascending order and I was trying to use bubble sort algorithm, but the compiler doesn't sort in the right order. I'm only allowed to use one function.

```
void sort3(int *a, int *b, int *c){   
        int array[3]= {*a, *b, *c};
        int temp, i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3-1;j++){
                if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                    temp=array[j];
                    array[j]=array[j+1];
                    array[j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Comment: @Aras This question is about C, the one you linked only applies to C++. Why do you think it is a duplicate?

Comment: algorithm in any language is the same as just syntax is different, you know that. so because of this, that question is duplicate.  and if you have a problem on C++ syntax change of your title to find a solution. also if I do something wrong, I'm sorry about that. have a great day and enjoy coding ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort the local array `array`, but you don't "return" the values back to the calling function.

Without knowing the full context it seems like you should assign back to what the pointers are pointing to:

```
*a = array[0];
*b = array[1];
*c = array[2];
```

Comment: Oh yes, my problem was that I was writing it other way. array[0] = *a and etc.  Sorry I'm very new to this

Comment: @user12102361 That's actually a different problem, and should have warranted a different answer. In the future please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).