# Using raw pointers when passing an object as a function argument

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Imagine following scenario

I have a classes `A` and `B`

```cpp
/* A class with a shared pointer */
class A {
public:
  //...

private:
  std::shared_ptr<object_t> m_ptr;
};

/* A class with an unique pointer */
class B {
public:
  //...

private:
  std::unique_ptr<object_t> m_ptr;
};
```

I want to have a function, which will use the object pointed by `m_ptr` and process it, but will not take ownership of it. Should the function take a smart pointer as an argument like

```cpp
void process(std::shared_ptr<object_t> obj);
```

or should it use a raw pointer like

```cpp
void process(object_t* obj);
```

**Edit:**

Apparently, I forgot about an important 3rd option for the function

```cpp
void process(object_t& obj);
```

which as pointed out by [kotatsuyaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12122460/kotatsuyaki) should be the preferred solution.

Comment: Have you considered using references?

Comment: Does a reference handle polymorphism? So would it call virtual functions from derived classes?

Comment: Yes, references have proper support for virtual functions. See [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058339/12122460).

Comment: Since it does not take ownership, the parameter should **not** be a `shared_ptr`.  If a `nullptr` is legitimate for the routine to handle, then `object_t*`.  If a `nullptr` is not legitimate for the routine, then `object_t&`.  All of them support polymorphism.

Comment: You should never pass a shared_ptr by value like your first example unless your intention is to actually share ownership with wherever that thing is going.