# Subtle error when using temporaries to get iterators to a STL container: how to avoid it?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, temporary-objects

Let's consider this class:

```
class X {
    std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> _map;
public:
    X() { /* Populate the map */ }

    std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> getTheMap() { return _map; }
};
```

and this buggy code:

```
X x;
// Statement 1
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>::const_iterator it = x.getTheMap().begin();
// Statement 2
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>::const_iterator et = x.getTheMap().end();

for (; it != et; it++) {
    /* Access the map using the iterator it */
}
```

The wrong part is that, in `Statement 1` and `Statement 2`, I'm getting an iterator to a temporary object which is going to be destroyed at the end of each statement.
As a result the behavior inside the `for()` loop is undefined.

A correct usage of the `getTheMap()` method would have been this:

```
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> map = x.getTheMap();
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>::const_iterator it = map.begin();
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>::const_iterator et = map.end();

for (/* [...] */)
```

It must be noted that class `X` has some serious design issues:

1. `_map` should be better encapsulated inside the class (both for read and write access), so the `getTheMap()` method could be avoided
2. If the `getTheMap()` method is really needed, it could return a reference to `_map`

However, given class X "as is" (<-- see edit below), is there a way to prevent users from getting the iterator to the temporary?

EDIT: class `X` can be changed, but `getTheMap` method should exist and return by value. however I was also thinking about compiler warnings.

Comment: If class X can't be changed, what do we have to work with?  Can class X be hidden, forcing users to use something else, like a wrapper class?

Comment: How about documentation.

Comment: @VaughnCato You are perfectly right :). I've added a note in the `EDIT` section at the end of the question.

Comment: What is the reason for continuing to return by value? Returing a reference and reference to const will not break old code.

Comment: You can't do anything, other than redesigning the class to not be crappy. If the user is not aware of this, they shouldn't write C++. Also, if you return the map by reference, you might as well make `_map` public.

Comment: @pmr I have containers of `boost::shared_ptr`, I preferred returning it by value to avoid memory issues with multiple threads (http://stackoverflow.com/a/327581/528313)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus yours is an acceptable answer, that's reasonable, exactly something I wanted to know. I wished there was some compiler flag I wasn't aware about, but, apparently, there isn't :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a wrapper like this:

```
class X {
  typedef std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t> Map;
  Map _map;

  struct MapWrap {
    const Map &mapref;

    MapWrap(const Map &mapref_arg)
    : mapref(mapref_arg)
    {
    }

    operator Map() const { return mapref; }
  };


public:
  MapWrap getTheMap()
  {
    return MapWrap(_map);
  }
};
```

so that you get this:

```
X x;
std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t>::const_iterator iter = x.getTheMap().begin(); // error
std::map<uint32_t,uint32_t> m = x.getTheMap(); // no error
```

This prevents accidentally using the temporary like a map, but makes it where the user has to use a copy of the map.

Comment: Also known as returning a proxy object.

Answer (score 1):

Not in C++03. In C++11 the Standard library should already have such protection enabled.

Comment: At least this confirms my question has a sense :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try forcing getTheMap() to return the original object by using std::move, but I'm not sure if that will work here.

If not, I guess returning a unique/shared_ptr of the member would be the best option.