# How to enforce const-correctness regarding pointer data-members

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

Following a discussion at work, we seem to be unable to enforce "logical" const-correctness on a class which has pointer data-members, as such:

```
class Widget {
public:
    void Foo();
    void FooConst() const;
};

class WidgetManager {
public:
    WidgetManager() : _pW(std::shared_ptr<Widget>(new Widget())) { }

    void ManagerFoo()
    {
        _pW->Foo();         // should be OK, will not compile if declared as "const Widget*"
        _pW->FooConst();    // should be OK
    }

    void ManagerFooConst() const
    {
        _pW->Foo();         // should NOT be OK, will not compile if declared as "const Widget*"
        _pW->FooConst();    // should be OK
    }

    void RegenerateWidget()
    {
        _pW = std::shared_ptr<Widget>(new Widget());
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> _pW;
};
```

As can be seen, we would like to have `WidgetManager::ManagerFooConst()` to not be able to call non-const functions of `WidgetManager`'s pointer members, while still allowing them to be called from other, non-const functions of `WidgetManager`. This means, declaring the pointer as `std::shared_ptr<const Widget>` (i.e. `const Widget*`) is out.

In addition, we would like the option to make the pointer reference another `Widget` during the manager's life-time, so we don't really want to hold it as a data-member (and can't hold it by reference).

Of course, all "bitwise" const-correctness is enforced here, as no data-members of `WidgetManager` can be modified from within const methods (including the specific `Widget` pointed by `_pW`), but we would like to achieve "logical" const-correctness were even pointed members can't be modified.

The only thing we came-up with is adding a const and non-const "getters of `this`" to `Widget`:

```
class Widget {
public:
    void Foo();
    void FooConst() const;

    Widget* GetPtr()    { return this; }
    const Widget* GetConstPtr() const   { return this; }
};
```

And reverting to use these instead of the arrow operator directly:

```
void WidgetManager::ManagerFoo()
{
    // shouldn't use "->" directly (lint?)

    _pW->GetPtr()->Foo();
    _pW->GetPtr()->FooConst();
    //_pW->GetConstPtr()->Foo();        // this won't compile (good)
    _pW->GetConstPtr()->FooConst();

}

void WidgetManager::ManagerFooConst() const
{
    // shouldn't use "->" directly (lint?)

    _pW->GetPtr()->Foo();               // shouldn't be used (lint?)
    _pW->GetPtr()->FooConst();          // shouldn't be used (lint?)
    //_pW->GetConstPtr()->Foo();        // this won't compile (good)
    _pW->GetConstPtr()->FooConst();
}
```

But this is so ugly, and definitely not enforceable by the compiler.

Specifically, trying to overload `operator->` for `Widget*` and `const Widget*` didn't seem to change anything: `ManagerFooConst()` was still able to call `_pW->Foo()`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use (or reimplement) [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

and then your code would be:

```
class Widget {
public:
    void Foo();
    void FooConst() const;
};

class WidgetManager {
public:
    WidgetManager() : _pW(std::make_shared<Widget>()) {}

    void ManagerFoo()
    {
        _pW->Foo();      // OK
        _pW->FooConst(); // OK
    }

    void ManagerFooConst() const
    {
        _pW->Foo();         // not compile
        _pW->FooConst();    // OK
    }

private:
    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> _pW;
};
```

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/KKNIzu)

Answer (score 2):

Consider accessing your `shared_ptr` through a member function that reflects the const-ness of `this` onto the pointed-to object.

```
class WidgetManager {

    ...

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> _pW;

    std::shared_ptr<Widget>& get_widget()
    {
        return _pW;
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<const Widget> get_widget() const
    {
        return _pW;
    }
}
```

You will get the one error you expect here.

```
void ManagerFoo()
{
    get_widget()->Foo();         // will be OK, will not compile if declared as "const Widget*"
    get_widget()->FooConst();    // will be OK
}

void ManagerFooConst() const
{
    get_widget()->Foo();         // will NOT be OK
    get_widget()->FooConst();    // will be OK
}
```

Comment: I _did_ regret that the const accessor returns a copy... but [here's solid confirmation for that choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960517/16287).

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to make const and non-const managers two different types:

```
template<class TWidget>
class WidgetManager {
    // ...
private:
    std::shared_ptr<TWidget> _pW;
};

WidgetManager<const Widget> const_wm;
const_wm.ManagerFoo(); // fail: _pW->Foo(): call non-const function of *_pw: a const Widget.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been proposed here you can introduce a concept of "owning pointer" based on shared pointer:

```
template<class T>
class owning_ptr {
    public:
    owning_ptr(T* data) : mData{data} {}
    // Put as many constructors as you need

    T* operator->() { return mData.get(); }
    const T* operator->() const { return mData.get(); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> mData;    
};
```

This class has same functionality as shared pointer but a different concept of owning data.

You would use it the same way you'd use shared pointer:

```
class WidgetManager {

    ...

private:
    owning_ptr<Widget> _pW;
}
```

Comment: `owning_ptr(T* data)`: It is **the** constructor to not use. simply take a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 it does not matter here