# Pass by reference vs. Pass by shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Most questions on Stackoverflow are asking about shared_ptr should be passed by ref or by value. However my question is exampled like this:

```
class Foo;

void function1(Foo & ff) { ff.m_abc = 1024; }
void function2(const std::shared_ptr<Foo> & ff) { ff->m_abc = 1024; }
```

The `function1` and `function2` may use and change some part of ff.

---

My case here:

I have a need for calling a function with an arg `*this` or `shared_from_this()`.

```
print(msg, *this);

or

print(msg, this->shared_from_this());
```

I can either use `function1` or `function2` style in my code for a function.

However, if I use `function2` style, I need to implement `Foo` to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but with `function1` style, I do not need to.

**I'm using this function in a single-threaded environment**

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here.

Comment: Just be sure to pass by value where you need to make sure the ref-count doesn't get to zero.

Comment: Either i am,  Also, by passing by shared_ptr, it means you need to check for nullptr.

Comment: I am assuming *some* other object already has a `shared_ptr` to `this`?  In that case, `print(msg, *(this->shared_from_this()))` makes `function1` behave identically to `function2`, assuming `function2` does not copy the `shared_ptr`

Comment: Nope, class Foo does not inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this now. I'd have to add this inheritance if I use the `function2` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing shared pointers as arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826541/passing-shared-pointers-as-arguments)

Comment: I don't see anything related between these two questions. @R.MartinhoFernandes

Answer (score 9):

You only pass the `shared_ptr` to a function if the function cares about there being a `shared_ptr`, usually because it wants to keep a copy, or a `weak_ptr`.

Anything else just reduces applicability of the function for no gain.

Comment: It will want to keep a copy at least for the duration of the function.  In a multithreaded environment this may be an issue.  I'm not sure I can agree with this answer.

Comment: It's the caller's responsibility to make sure that the references it gives to a function don't become invalid while the function is running. Anything else is insane. And if the caller has a `shared_ptr` on its stack, you're safe.

Comment: And if the `shared_ptr` the source has can be modified by more than one thread, neither solution is safe.

Comment: And if `function1` actually stores the pointer in a `vector <shared_ptr> (&ff)` which is used by a worker thread, what then?

Comment: @JohnDibling Then you shoot your developers for screwing up 3 ways from Sunday.  Creating a `shared_ptr` from a reference?  Bad.  Creating a `shared_ptr` for a resource you did not create?  Bad.  Creating a `shared_ptr` for a resource you did not create that is `enable_shared_from_this` instead of calling `shared_from_this`?  They better bring donuts.

Comment: In multithreading environment, we should adopt `void function3(std::shared_ptr<Foo> ff);` which copies the ptr and make sure it has at least one ref to the resource so that it'll not be deleted by other threads.

Comment: Every environment is multi-threaded, unless you plan to never reuse your code, ever. Are you saying we should not use references anymore? You use by-val parameters on functions that you start new threads with; those should be pretty easy to identify. And if you start a thread/async task for some existing function that takes by-ref, you just wrap it, possibly in a lambda.

Comment: The comment on multi-threaded environments makes no sense to me. If the shared pointer exists in the caller, you don't need to make a new copy of it for the duration of the function. Reference is perfectly safe. Edit: @SebastianRedl perfectly commented above.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a `shared_ptr` if you want to share the ownership of the object with the function you're calling, that is if you want to make sure the object will be alive as long as the function needs it.

One case where this is important is if your function does an asynchronous operation, it might want to use your object once the operation is finished and by that time your object might have been deleted so if you passed by reference, that reference is dangling, while if you passed `shared_from_this()`, you are guaranteed that the life time of your object will be extended to as long as the function needs it. (Most [code samples of `boost::asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) for example are based on this logic).