# Object destruction when function getting ownership of unique_ptr throws exception

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

If function `Foo()` transfers ownership of `std::unique_ptr` to function `Bar()` and say `Bar()` throws an exception, object contained in `std::unique_ptr` will get destroyed.

How can one handle a case where `Foo()` might want to keep the ownership with itself in such cases.

```
class A
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeData> getSomeData(...);
};

class B
{
public:
    pushToQ(std::unique_ptr<SomeData>);
    doSomething()
    ...
    popFromQ();
    ...
};
```

Now if `B::pushToQ()` throws `QueueFullException` I will loose the data generated by `getSomeData()` which I might not want.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/10826541/332733

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs. I will go with the solution suggested by Barry and Mgetz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're either transferring ownership - or you're not. If you want to transfer, then you shouldn't care if `Bar` can throw and kill your object:

```
// i do not care what bar does with ptr, i am done with it
bar(std::move(ptr));
```

If you *might* want to retain ownership *maybe*, then transferring ownserhip is the wrong solution. Either you want to pass your `unique_ptr` by reference, or maybe just pull out the raw pointer, or maybe even just use a `shared_ptr`. It depends on your use-case. But there's no half-way ownership transfer.

Here are some examples. Which is preferred is entirely up to you:

```
bar(std::unique_ptr<Data>& ptr) {
    // not transferring, caller still owns the data
    something_that_might_throw();
    something_that_might_not();

    // ok got here?
    std::unique_ptr<Data> myPtr = std::move(ptr);
    // MINE NOW!!!
}
```

The above is "the ONLY exception safe solution to moving a unique_ptr into a container in an exception safe manner with a strong guarantee that the system won't be corrupted" (from [MGetz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914534/object-destruction-when-function-getting-ownership-of-unique-ptr-throws-exceptio/26914673?noredirect=1#comment42379175_26914673))

Or:

```
bar(Data* ptr) {
    // it really doesn't matter, caller always owns the data
    // just don't go doing something like this

    std::unique_ptr<Data> awful_idea(ptr);

    // now two separate people both think they own the data
    // and will both try to delete it. That'll work the first time...
}
```

Or a strictly better version so you can't mess it up unless you try really hard

```
bar(Data& data) {
    // well clearly the caller owns it
}
```

Or:

```
bar(std::shared_ptr<Data> ptr) {
    // we both share the data
    // it won't get deleted until both bar() and caller delete it
}
```

Comment: @Mgetz can you please explain on how I can achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: @Mgetz how would an exception in the `shared_ptr` case cause data loss?

Comment: Related: [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Comment: @Barry the solution you don't like is the ONLY exception safe solution to moving a `unique_ptr` into a container in an exception safe manner with a strong guarantee that the system won't be corrupted. Passing the `unique_ptr` by value means that the ownership is transferred on call, which is not desired if the function might throw and should ONLY be used if the function is `nowthrow`

Comment: @Barry because I'm lazy and 99% of yours is spot on

Comment: @Mgetz Ha! With the amount of suggestions you've thrown around here, I'm not sure I buy lazy :-P

Answer (score 2):

Then don't transfer the ownership.

Pass a `SomeData&` into `Bar()`, instead.

Comment: use the former to indicate ownership transfer may occur and the latter to indicate it won't occur

Comment: or just a `SomeData&` and deference the `unique_ptr` if it's known to be valid.

Comment: I do not see how that solves his issue. He wants to push object into queue, how is passing by reference is solving the issue? Make a copy and push it into queue?

Comment: @Slava he wants to pass the object without giving up ownership as far as I can tell, so how does this not do it?

Comment: @PeterT function name is `pushToQ()` exception possible thrown is QueueFullException, does not ring a bell?

Comment: @Slava hm, well the only thing that comes to mind then would be passing an rvalue I guess. I just don't know how to communicate whether ownership was take or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr` and release your instance if pushToQ() succeded, keep your copy otherwise.

Comment: Seems like a blunt instrument. You're weakening your entire design's ownership contracts as a cheap way to work around a resolvable problem!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit At least it is obvious what is happening looking into code. Passing `std::unique_ptr` as a reference hides that fact and makes code less readable. So it is at least questionable which solution is cheaper.

Comment: Yeah, granted, that was a bit of a misstep. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the called function, store the `unique_ptr` in the thrown exception object. If the callee - or some other function up the call stack - wants to save it, it can then be extracted. If not, it will be safely destroyed.